# Браузер имитация телефона

Tags: yii2, apache, tcp-ip, mobile, mac-address

Коллеги столкнулся с такой проблемой.
На ссайте сломана Мобильная версия ссайта.
К сожалению мобильная версия это не верстка а что-то более грубое что когда-то сделали.
Для перехода на мобильную верстку ссайта нужно что бы сам устройство было мобильным. Так как идёт сканирование по Юзер агенту и т.д. Скажите есть ли приложения, службы для браузера имитирующие не только разрешение мобильного устройства но и апаратную состовляющию (Юзер агент, мак адрес и т.д.) Потому что разработчик до меня так и сделал. Проверку не на разрешение экрана а на то какое устройство подключаеться. Так вот есть ли возможность в браузере или ещё как-то с имитировать то что к нему подключаеться не десктоп а мобильное устройство? И да ссайт который сломан в локальной сети. Я думал поискать онлайн сервисы но они будут не доступны в моём случае. Да забыл сказать ссайт создан на YII я искал там документацию по этому вопросу но не нашёл..

Comment: В консоли разработчика браузера есть мобильный режим, там можно выбрать устройство, которое будет имитироваться.

Comment: Не срабатывает, изменяет только верстку

Comment: нужно полная имитация, будто бы это мобильное устройство. Модификация трафика, настройка низкого уровня и т.д. А не только изменение размера экрана

Comment: Тогда сервисы используйте, правда они платные, но вроде дают полную имитацию.